# How do I sum a list of numbers while ignoring duplicate numbers?

Tags: python

I need help trying to sum up numbers in a list while ignoring duplicates. Let's say I have a list [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3] the answer should be 6 because 1 + 2 + 3 = 6. The extra 2 and extra 3s should not be included in the calculation.

```
def sumOfUniqueNums(list):

    sum = 0

    list1 = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
    remove = []
    [remove.append(i) for i in list1 if i not in remove]

    sum(list1)

    return sum
```

## Updated function

```
def sumOfUniqueNums(numbers):
    return sum(set(numbers))
```

Comment: I'm using Python language.

Comment: use a set for this. `sum(set(list1))`

Comment: so the updated function works for you now? If so, I would recommend accepting one of the below answers

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [set](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) cannot contain duplicate values, so it's as simple as

```
sum(set(list1))
```

Python will let you override built-in names, though, so you'll need to unassign `sum` before this will work.

Comment: I'm getting an error: line 9, in sumOfUniqueNums
    sum(set(list1)) 
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: probably because you have set sum = 0 before trying this line? The above line should be all that is in your function, apart from the return keyword perhaps

Comment: make sure you don't use 'sum' or 'list' as variable names as they clash with reserved names in python(sum is already a function, and list is a type of data structure)

Comment: So all I should have in my function/code is: def sumOfUniqueNums(list): return sum(set(numbers))

Comment: @user2581724 but your updated function uses `list` for its formal parameters and `numbers` inside it. That can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should work fine:

```
def sumOfUniqueNums(values):
    return sum(set(values))

print sumOfUniqueNums([1,1,2,2])
3

print sumOfUniqueNums([1,1,2,2,3])
6
```